# JavaScript: Retry when GET fails

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am trying to get an HTML5 audio element to reload its source via JavaScript when the audio stream is interrupted. Due to the fact that it's a live stream for a radio station, I want the script to keep reloading the source until it's live.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("ended",function() {
        this.src = "mysource/stream";
        this.play();
    });
</script>
```

This script is functioning perfectly but it finishes running if there is no audio coming from the stream (GET fails).

Is there a way to set it so that it keeps retrying loading the source till the stream server is back online?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059309/check-if-video-is-streaming, I think also it depends on your player api.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ thanks for answering. I am not using any player just an html5 audio element.

Comment: I know, I do normally only use api but as standard htlm5 I need to think about it.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ this code really need some ajax I suppose. Ajax with retry functionality would be great